# How to use dot delimited string as object path for vue v-model directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have data record

```
record: {
  address: {
   city: ""
  }
}
```

array of objects that describe field

```
fields: [ 
  {
    name: "address.city"
    ...
  }
]
```

and try to generate form

```
    <b-field
      v-for="field in fields"
      :key="field.name"
      :label="field.label"
    >
      <b-input v-model="record[field.name]" />
    </b-field>
```

and get object item with key like `address.name`
I understand that i should pass to v-model `record[address][city]` but how to do it from dot delimited string?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const getPathInObject = (path, object) => {
  const [current, ...rest] = path.split('.')
  return rest.length === 0
    ? object[current]
    : getPathInObject(rest.join('.'), object[current])
}

document.write(getPathInObject('a.b.c.d', { a: { b: { c: { d: 'hello' } } } }))
```

**EDIT** maybe something like this. verry hacky though

```js
const unflatten = obj => {
  const result = {};
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const [a, b] = key.split('.');
    result[a] ||= {};
    result[a][b] = value
  })
  return result
}


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    record_flat: {"address.city": '', "address.country": ''},
    fields: [ 
  {   name: "address.city", label: 'city'  },
  {   name: "address.country", label: 'country'  }
]
  },
  computed: {
    record: ({ record_flat }) => unflatten(record_flat),
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="{name, label}  in fields" :key="name">
     <label>{{ label }}</label><input v-model="record_flat[name]" /> 
     <br>
  </div>
  <hr>Value of record = {{ record }}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, its get nested value, but it doesn't work as v-model parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I used `:value` and `@input` instead `v-model`.
And lodash `get` and `set`

```
      <b-input
        :value="get(data, field.name)"
        @input="set(data, field.name, $event)"
      />
```